# Short Cut Key to put MS Outlook into Offline Mode

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a short cut key to put MS Outlook into Offline Mode?  I'm running Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a shortcut key, with 2 clicks you are done:

> File | Work Offline

Or

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Alt-F, Alt-K works for me!

Comment: In a German Outlook 2019 it is `Alt+S` and `L`. (ALT+S activates the tab "Senden/Empfangen" and L is the shortcut to toggle "Offline arbeiten")

Answer (score 5):

The right shortcut should be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>FK</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: +1 for adding accuracy. Note that Alt then F then K works as well - you don't need to hold Alt when selecting from menu's. In fact holding Alt+F then holding Alt+K doesn't work for me (in Outlook 2003 at least) as the second Alt closes the menu.

Answer (score 4):

And in Outlook 2010 it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SW</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 - Windows

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2016 here.

I confirm, that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SW</kbd> works fine.
But if you looking for something even faster then add "Work Offline"  button to Quick Access Toolbar and then you can use a little bit faster shortcut like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DIGIT</kbd>, for example - in my case - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Outlook für Office 365 MSO (16.0.11629.20192) 32-Bit

<kbd>Alt</kbd> --> <kbd>S</kbd> --> <kbd>L</kbd>